# error in version change

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

When i'm using an XSLT statement for transforming and it is as below.

```
<xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::title/@num and contains(./item/@num,'•')">
```

when i'm using XSLT1.0 version there is no issue, but when i'm changing the version to 2.0, it is throwing the below error, please let me know how i can fix this.

```
XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: Error: file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/MAL/Malaysian%20Civil%20Procedure%202013/XSLT/new_bull%20-%20Cols.xsl:704: Wrong occurrence to match required sequence type -   Details: -     XPTY0004: The supplied sequence ('4' item(s)) has the wrong occurrence to match the sequence type xs:string ('zero or one')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `contains((./item/@num)[1],'•')` to make sure there is only one node as the first argument to `contains`.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains, the specification indicates with `fn:contains($arg1 as xs:string?, $arg2 as xs:string?) as xs:boolean` that the first argument needs to be an empty sequence or a single item, the error message `The supplied sequence ('4' item(s))` suggests that in your code `./item/@num` selects four items.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the solution, but can you please tell me where the mistake i've done.

Comment: With XSLT/XPath 1.0, if the first argument to `contains` is a set of several nodes, the string of the first node is taken. With XSLT/XPath 2.0, the rules are different, the first argument has to be an empty sequence or a single item, if not, if you pass in a sequence of several items, you get an error. That means that in your case `./item/@num` selects more than one node, your context node has more than one `item` child element with a `num` attribute and passing all those `num` attributes in to the `contains` function causes the error.